# Local are Network DNS and IP settings

Tags: router, dns, lan

I want to set up a small network with four computers, a tablet, an Arduino with a network shield and a wireless router. I want to give everything a permanent IP address and run WAMP on one of the computers.  All of the other devices will communicate with each other using the WAMP server.  This little network will never be connected to the internet at large.  What is the best way to set up the IP addresses, gateway, DNS setting, and other settings I may not be thinking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "All of the other devices will communicate with each other using the WAMP server"? WAMP is simply a Windows Apache MySQL PHP stack so all it does is allow you create and serve web applications...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the hassle of maintaining your IP connection settings on each and every machine, you could set up a DHCP server on your main always-on server and give addresses / options through it. This is useful when you want to globally set a domain-name search, other boot options, or "monitor" your IP address usage. In that case you'd have to use static IP addresses given on a per-MAC basis.
You could even, if needed in the future, create a small IP pool for dynamically allocated addresses (useful for smartphones or temporary clients that do not need a reserved address).

Answer (score 1):

You already have everything you need... your wireless router (I will assume) is probably your home/SoHo modem/router all-in-one?

If so then this will have all the DHCP, DNS, gateway etc. already configured and you simply connect your devices.

If you want certain devices to always have the same IPs then log on to the wireless router's web GUI and assign them a "reserved" IP. This will record the device MAC address and the IP you specify (within the subnet range of the DHCP server).

You're making this question much harder than you need to as almost all modem/routers have this ability built-in...